# Objective-C Key-Value Observing

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, key-value-observing

```
[sessionController.currentSession addObserver:self
                            forKeyPath:@"sessionState"
                               options:(NSKeyValueChangeSetting)
                               context:NULL];
```

This doesn't seem to be working.

The class where this code goes knows about the sessionController and has access to the currentSession. The sessionState variable of the currentSession is what I want to observe. Is it *verboten* to set the object to be observed in the way I've done it here?

If so, what is the way to do it? Short of giving the observing object a currentSession variable.

Comment: you implemented `observeValueForKeyPath:ofObject:change:context:` in self right? And you ensured that it is not ever being called?

Comment: Also what is the type of currentSession?

Comment: Yes, observeValueForKeyPath:ofObject:change:context: is implemented in self, and is working for other stuff. It is not getting called at all -- even outside of the switching -- for this. It is getting called for other stuff, as it should. Current Session is a subclass of NSManagedObject, for which I have actual .h and .m files.

Comment: And `sessionState` is implemented in the Current Session subclass with `@property` and `@dynamic`?

Comment: I couldn't make any headway with that problem, so I switched to using an NSNotification. Now all is well.

Comment: Sorry for all the questions, was trying to narrow the problem done. There are issues where if you implement the accessor methods yourself for a NSManagedObject subclass, then KVO notifications are turned off buy Core Data, so you have to manually do the notifications. But it seems like you did it all correct, so I can't think of what the problem could be.

Comment: Don't be sorry! Thanks for all the questions. I really appreciate it.

Comment: Is sessionController.currentSession set when you call this? If not, you are trying to observe nil, which will never be triggered. Also, if you want to observe the sessionState of the currentSession after the currentSession changes, you should use [sessionController addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"currentSession.sessionState" ...] so that the observation changes when the currentSession changes

Answer (score 0):

Does sessionController.currentSession contain a valid value when you call the method?

This is a common pitfall, and sending a message to null will fail silently.